# kue - Processing jobs in different file

Tags: javascript, node.js, kue

I want my queue.process function to be in a separate file, but `module.exports` doesn't work.

kue.js:

```
var kue = require('kue');
module.exports = function() {
  var queue = kue.createQueue();
  queue.process('test', function(job, done) {
    console.log('job processed.');
    done();
  }
}
```

server.js:

```
require('./kue');
//server stuff
```

There are no errors. I also have a separate function queuing jobs and its working. The problem seems to be in importing kue.js file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are exporting a function in kue.js, but you aren't calling that function when you require it. Try

```
 require('./kue')();
```

Comment: That's silly of me, thanks, I totally forgot that I need to invoke a function.

Answer (score 1):

You should require name the function you are exporting for example

```
module.exports.proccess = function()...
```

Comment: That works, but Robert's answer is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Glad that you found a solution :)